# How to save columns in .txt whit condition VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm a beginer with VBA and I'd like to know where I went wrong with my code.

```
Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        If 
         code
        End If

        Application.EnableEvents = True:
        If Range("A3") <> Range("B4") Then
         Columns("B1:F10000").Select
         ChDir "C:\Users\Francesco\Desktop"
         ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs:="C:\Users\Francesco\Desktop\TXT.txt", _
         FileFormat:=xlTextMSDOS, CreateBackup:=False
        End If            
    End Sub
```

My focus is: when the condition `If Range("A3") <> Range("B4")` is true,I'd like that vba creates a .txt.

Where I wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: if you only want to save text in one column as txt file, the easier approach is to copy the column to a new file, then save the file as txt file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This:

```
Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

        If Range("A3") <> Range("B4") Then

            ActiveSheet.Range("B1:F10000").Select
            ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\Users\Francesco\Desktop\TXT.txt", FileFormat:=xlTextMSDOS, CreateBackup:=False

        End If

End Sub
```

As per your code you are saving the entire Worksheet. So i don't see any point of selecting the Columns.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
I'm going to write your code and test it.

Comment: Thank you so much, it's working!!! :)
I have a question. 
Why the file is too big (the columns are five and the rows are 10.000)?
 How I can to save it in a light way?

Comment: That's because you are saving the Entire Worksheet, not the columns that you selected. One way can be to copy and paste those columns on a new workbook and save that workbook as a text file. That will make it lighter.

Comment: Okay, thank you so much for you answer. 
I'm going to do this.

Comment: @Francesco ... Accept it as Answer if it worked for you. For any other users looking for answers can see.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim wb as workbook, wb1 as workbook
set wb = activeworkbook
set wb1 = application.workbooks.new

If Range("A3") <> Range("B4") Then
     wb.activate
     Columns("B1:F10000").copy
     wb1.activate
     range("A1").paste
     ChDir "C:\Users\Francesco\Desktop"
     wb1.SaveAs:="C:\Users\Francesco\Desktop\TXT.txt", FileFormat:=xlTextMSDOS, CreateBackup:=False
     call wb1.close(false)
End If
```

Not tested.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Function SimpleWriteToText(ByVal FileName, ByVal strText, Optional Wtype = "output")
If Wtype = "output" Then
    Open FileName For Output As #1
Else
    Open FileName For Append As #1
End If
        Print #1, strText;
    Close #1
End Function
```

Usage

```
SimpleWriteToText ThisWorkbook.path & "\Text.txt", "Hello"  ' Append
SimpleWriteToText ThisWorkbook.path & "\Text.txt", "Hello", "output"  ' NewOne
```